# Jupyter notebook gives no error but doesn't open port connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect and use jupyter notebooks on a Windows remote desktop. I can install jupyter fine and even run it perfectly, but whenever I try to access the notebook via browser, I get a "can't reach" message for localhost:8888.

After some extensive research online, where people just needed to change 127.0.0.1 to localhost or vice versa, or changed their browser, nothing seemed to work. Some threads also suggested I change up the config file and instead run `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888`. Furthermore, I tried using several different ports and even asked the IT administrator which port is definetly available, but this was all to no avail.

Delving deeper into the problem, I checked whether jupyter opened a port connection on the remote desktop by running `netstat -aon | findstr :*port*` in the terminal. This was **not** the case.

I'm dumbfounded how jupyter notebook doesn't return an error while not actually creating a port connection on the remote machine. Seeing as I can easily set up a port connection through `python -m http.server 8888` I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any idea on why jupyter doesn't seem to open a port connection and how this can be remedied?

Comment: Just to be sure - you are running both jupyter *and* browser on the remote desktop? Also, when you start jupter, you see a message like `Jupyter Server is running at http://localhost:8888/lab?token=...`?

Comment: @psarka , yes I am running them both on the remote desktop. The prompt from Jupyter is exactly like how it should be: `Jupyer Notebook 6.4.8 is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=...`